# How can I backup media from a tablet to my Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: backup, tablet

I have Ubuntu 12.10 and a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0  How can I use my desktop to back up my tablet?  I tried to call Samsung support earlier, but they wanted $200 for their tech support!

Answer (score 1):

**short answer**: install the rsync deamon on your linux box, then install the rsync tool of your choice on your tablet and then run the backup from the Android device.

**long answer**

1. start the rsync daemon (see for example http://www.fredshack.com/docs/rsync.html). you can do this just once, or make sure it is always loaded at boot by adding it to the /etc/initd.conf
2. for example use "rsync backup for Android" it is very straightforward and get the job done (see https://sensortower.com/android/de/michal-kowalczuk/app/rsync-backup-for-android/eu.kowalczuk.rsync4android for more info)
   3.1 make sue your Linux and Android boxes are on the same (wifi) network (includes being powered on etc.)

3.2 on your Linux box type ifconfig and identify your relevant ip-address

3.3 fire up the "rsync backup for Android" on the small device, click [menu] and then [add profile]

3.4 there you fill out all the details (including the ip-address of the Linux box and the rsync options (you might want to consult the man pages, but -av is probably what you need). Then click [Save profile]

3.5 execute the backup from the device

PS: optional: configure your Linux box to use  a fixed ip-address

... total cost $0.00